# Evaluate the point limit

Tags: limits

I needed to find this point limit:$$\lim_{n\to \infty} n^2x^n$$ where $x\in R$. Where should this exist on the real line $R$ except at $x=0$?

For $x=1, x=-1, \vert x\vert >1$; I guess the limit does not exist. But I have a bit of confusion about $\vert x\vert < 1$.

Need help.

Comment: Consider four cases: $|x| \lt 1$, $x=-1$, $x=1$, $|x| \gt 1$.

Comment: Got it. The limit exists for $\vert x \vert<1$. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $x=\pm1, x<-1$ and $x>1$, the limit does not exist as is clearly seen. It only exists for $|x|<1$. In short for $x\in (-\infty,1]\cup[1,\infty)$, the limit does not exist.